# Ruby on Rails Quickstart

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just completed a couple of Ruby on Rails books which were excellent. I'd like to know if there are any quickstarts or guides that can serve to jumpstart to my RoR projects but without all of the explanations that I have search through to get the steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply running `rails new <project>` will "jumpstart" things for you, in that you'll have a working Rails app. Using the generators will further stub out the project, letting you "fill in the blanks". Anything beyond this is up to you - how much more of a "jumpstart" do you need?

Comment: completely agree with @meagar

Comment: Thanks meager, I guess I may be looking for more of the process of filling in the blanks. Somewhat of a 'Cliff notes' version of the books.

Comment: @basheps "Filling in the blanks" in this case is the actual process of writing software. The only thing left after using generators is to *write the application*. That part can't be any more jumpstarted than it already is. If the books you read didn't tell you how to do this, they weren't very good books, or you didn't understand them. Do you actually have an application in mind? What are you trying to build?

Comment: I'm trying to build a task management application. The books actually were good and I guess I really only need to review them and extract the portions that I need. I was trying to see if there was something that had been done already - the books are really long and I'm very new to RoR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't understand since you have read **a couple** of books and guides, why you would still need a quickstart guide to develop your own app. Rather contradicting. Why don't you just start developing an app from scratch with your awesome idea?

Anyway, to answer your question, try [Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) to build a Twitter app.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

(Caveats: I'm too new to post many links so you may need to copy/paste. Not all of these are for the most current versions of Ruby/Rails but they will certainly get you going.)

## CLONE TUTORIALS

**Twitter Clone**
[railsforzombies.org](http://railsforzombies.org/)

**Pinterest Clone**
[guides.railsgirls.com/app/](http://guides.railsgirls.com/app/)

**Good Reads Clone**
[zero-to-sixty-creating-and-deploying-a-rails-app-in-under-an-hour](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/zero-to-sixty-creating-and-deploying-a-rails-app-in-under-an-hour--net-8252)

(You will need to do some things differently in Rails 3/4 and just skip the Authlogic stuff altogether.)

## GENERAL STARTS

**Ruby Guide**
[getting_started.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) (also noted above)

**Sitepoint Tutorial**
[building-your-first-rails-application-models](http://sitepoint.com/building-your-first-rails-application-models/)

## STARTER APPLICATIONS

**Bort**
[github.com/MattHall/bort/tree/master](https://github.com/MattHall/bort/tree/master)

**BaseApp2**
[github.com/dannymcc/BaseApp2](https://github.com/dannymcc/BaseApp2) (requires QT SDK @ qt-project.org)

**Boilerplate**
[github.com/npverni/rails-boilerplate-script](https://github.com/npverni/rails-boilerplate-script/tree/master)

## SPECIFIC USE STARTER APPS

**Community Engine**
[communityengine.org](http://communityengine.org/)

**Tog**
[toghq.com](http://toghq.com)

**Open Source Rails**
[opensourcerails.com](http://opensourcerails.com/) (Library of apps; build on the shoulders of giants, geniuses/genii, and semi-talented braggarts)

Answer (score 2):

How about this one? 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 1):

If you read Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example then you should be good to go.  If not you could go through that book it is free online [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/).